# First tutotial: Starting Your Node

Tags: substrate

I just spent some time setting up my node following the first tutorial. For some reason, when launching the node, it throws this error:

```
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  WARN Running in --dev mode, RPC CORS has been disabled.    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO Substrate Node    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO ✌️  version 2.0.0-655bfdc-x86_64-linux-gnu    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2020    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO  Chain specification: Development    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO   Node name: abaft-jar-7208    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO  Role: AUTHORITY    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/substratefBeKdR/chains/dev/db    
Dec 04 11:09:40.546  INFO ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-1 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Looking at the expected outputs, it looks like this takes place when intialising the genesis block.

I've just started learning about all this, so may be a quite basic issue (e.g. an incompatible version or something). I didn't find any previous question on this, but please do let me know if this has been asked before.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of computer are you using? Is it by any chance an old Mac or one of the new ones with the M1 chip?

Comment: Just an old desktop running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Depending on how old the hardware is it's possible that there is some instruction that we need that's not supported. Do you know what CPU chip you're using? If you haven't made any changes to the Node Template I'm not immediately sure what would cause this problem...

Comment: No, I don't think I have modified any bit of the template. I'm currently using an Intel Core™2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz × 4

Comment: Also, is there any way to get the full traceback of the error to understand what's going on under the hood?

Comment: Hm, unfortunately in this case I am not too sure. It looks like it has to do with the instruction set that is available on your machine. I'm assuming you compiled the binary on the same machine that you're using to execute it. Maybe look into where Rust puts its core dumps or maybe if there are environment variables so it will show on the command line.